# How to include tinymce to symfony project and template using assetic

Tags: symfony, twig, tinymce, assetic, symfony-2.8

Im trying to include tinymce 4.5.5 to my Symfony project using `Assetic`

```
{% block javascripts %}
{% javascripts  '@MyAmazingBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
                ... 
                '@MyAmazingBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce.min.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

I [downloaded](https://www.tinymce.com/download/) `TinyMCE Community` and copied file tinymce.min.js to my Resources. I have got error:

```
TypeError: u is not a constructor
```

I researched that `u` is `Theme` so i tested some things and changed include by adding whole tinemce directory to resources + new declaration:

```
@MyAmazingBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js
```

I think Assetic breaking it because I tryied to include tinymce file from cloud and it worked but when i downloaded code from cloud and icluded from resources it was again broken in other way (not visible etc - something not worked)

I also tested some other ways to include it but nothing worked...

What is the correct way to add tinymce to symfony project/bundle and include to **template**?

**// EDIT**

I tryied include it by asset function and it worked so probably assetic breaking it by making copy of this file but anyway how to fix it?

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/myamazing/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Check files permissions.

Comment: which files and permissions? files in `Resources/public` are not all public and avaiable for everyone ? Obviously I called asset install so its visible from web folder.